# why we can pass a contravariance in a covariance type example of the List in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I'm wondering why I can pass a contravariance in a covariance type example of the List

I created this interface as you can see `I` is a contravariance but I was able to pass to the list

```
interface ListMapper<in I, out O> : Mapper<List<I>, List<O>>
```

if you check you will see that the list accept a Covariance type

```
public interface List<out E> : Collection<E> {...}
```

Why and how can this be possible ?

Comment: "I" is a contravariance for ListMapper, not for List you are passing to Mapper and for mapper contravariance is not "I" but "List<I>"

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the first type in the `Mapper` interface is contravariant at the declaration site.

There's no reason for the restriction you're imagining should be there. The covariance of the List is internal to the List functionality, and has nothing to do with the Mapper's functionality.

A List is covariant, meaning it cannot consume any `T`, so maybe it will simplify your understanding to replace it with a non-generic class that doesn't consume anything, such as `Int`, which is immutable. It looks obviously acceptable logically:

```
interface IntMapper : Mapper<Int, Int>
```

It's no different than with the `List`. You have a type that doesn't consume anything, yet it can be the input for a Mapper.

---

Answering your follow-up question from the comment:

The `K` type of HashMap is invariant at the declaration site. To simplify this dicussion, let's just use `MutableList` which also has an invariant type (so we aren't confused by Map's second `V` type).

Let's also simplify and use a more basic interface that just consumes, so we aren't confused by the second type in Mapper:

```
interface Consumer<in I>
```

So now we have:

```
// Allowed:
class ListConsumer<in I> : Consumer<List<I>>

// Not allowed:
class MutableListConsumer<in I> : Consumer<MutableList<I>> // Compile error
```

Imagine you have a ListConsumer. Since ListConsumer is contravariant, it allows you to cast a `ListConsumer<Number>` to the more restrictive type `ListConsumer<Int>`:

```
val numberListConsumer: ListConsumer<Number> = //...
val intListConsumer: ListConsumer<Int> = numberListConsumer
```

This makes sense. If you can consume `List<Number>`, then it is safe to consume any `List<Int>` because a `List<Int>` is also a `List<Number>` due to `List`'s covariant type.

But it doesn't make sense with MutableList. A `MutableList<Int>` is not a `MutableList<Number>` because MutableList's type is invariant.

Comment: Thank you very much this case was clear for me, but could you please clarify more about this case for example: Mapper<HashMap<I, Int>, O> then it say that the `Type parameter I is declared as 'in' but occurs in 'invariant'` why in the invariant case this happen ?

Comment: @OmarRedani see my update to the answer.